# Windows Server Downgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, downgrade

I work at a school district, and we are trying to find a way to downgrade our Servers. We recently upgraded to **Windows Server 2012R2**, and want to find a way to go back down to **Windows Server 2008R2**. This is just a backup option incase things don't go well with the new one.

I was told there is some kind of command that you can use to accomplish this, but I am not too sure of what that would be.

Thanks in advance, 
Viraj

Comment: Test first, then upgrade.

Comment: One solution is to build the new OS on new/different hardware.  The downgrade path is to plug in the old server again.  Having worked in schools, the cost is a stumbling block.

Comment: [Are you sure you want to do this?](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/lifecycle/search?alpha=server%202008%20r2)

Comment: "This is just a backup option ...." NO this is not a backup option. You do have an _actual_ backup right?

Comment: Thanks everyone. When I try and upgrade the server, it's as simple as clicking a button. Is there anything in the software where I can decrease the version? Or something that can be typed into Microsoft PowerShell?

Comment: Another question. What does this command do: DISM/Online/Set-Edition:ServerStandard/ProductKey:xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/AcceptEula

Comment: Restore to a 2008R2 backup if you have one, if you don't, cross your fingers for 2012 to work

Comment: For the command, seems like it is used to upgrade an Edition (for example, going from standard, to web, to Enterprise...) not versions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no Windows built-in way to downgrade an installed OS version, except for uninstalling service packs. This is not your case, as you are asking for a significant major version rollback.

You may be able to downgrade functional levels of certain components, particularly after installing new servers with the older version - but definitely no way back for the entire OS short of re-install.

See MDMarra's answer as well for external ways to manage your image.  Options include snapshotting VMs, dual booting, native-boot from VHDX, backup...

Answer (score 19):

This is not something that's built in to the OS installation.

Your two options are:

1. Use snapshotting at the hypervisor or storage layer if this server is a virtual machine. Roll back the snapshot on failure.
2. Take a full system backup that is capable of being used for a bare-metal restore. If the upgrade fails, restore from this backup.

Comment: Yep, these are good options external to the OS install itself. (+1)  Using that point of view, you can also native boot the server from .VHD(X) or dual-boot.